# How to see if a type implements an interface?

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, typechecking

I need to know if a `Type` implements an interface.

```
 Dim asmRule As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Rule.dll"))

 For Each typeAsm As System.Type In asmRule.GetTypes
     If TypeOf typeAsm Is Rule.IRule Then
       'that does always return false even though they implement IRule'
     End If
 Next
```

Thanks to all. Now i know why typeof didn't work. The type naturally does not implement IRule. I have filtered out two options from your answers:

1. `GetType(Rule.IRule).IsAssignableFrom(typeAsm)`
2. `typeAsm.GetInterface(GetType(Rule.IRule).FullName) IsNot Nothing`

What is the better choise according to performance?

**UPDATE**: i've found out that it might be better to use:

```
Not typeAsm.GetInterface(GetType(Rule.IRule).FullName) Is Nothing
```

instead of

```
GetType(Rule.IRule).IsAssignableFrom(typeAsm)
```

because the Interface IRule itself is assignable of IRule what raises a MissingMethodExcpetion if i try to create an instance:

```
ruleObj = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(typeAsm, True), Rule.IRule)
```

**UPDATE2:**
Thanks to Ben Voigt. He convinced me that IsAssignableFrom in combination with IsAbstract might be the best way to check if a given type implements an interface and **is not** the interface itself (what throws a MissingMethodException if you  try to create an instance).

```
If GetType(Rule.IRule).IsAssignableFrom(typeAsm) AndAlso Not typeAsm.IsAbstract Then
```

Comment: The C# `is` keyword will not work here.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: yes, most classes in this dll implement IRule interface, but TypeOf typeAsm Is Rule.IRule always returns false.

Comment: That's because the `System.Type` class doesn't implement `IRule`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`TypeOf ... Is` works fine with inheritance:

```
Imports System

Public Class Test

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim o As Object = 5

        If TypeOf o Is IFormattable Then
            Console.WriteLine("Yes")
        End If
    End Sub    

End Class
```

That works the same way as "is" in C#.

However, in your example, that's trying to see whether `System.Type` (or whatever subclass is actually used) implements `Rule.IRule`. That *won't* work... because you're not interested in whether `System.Type` implements the interface, you're interested in whether the *instance* of `System.Type` that the `typeAsm` variable refers to implements `IRule.Rule`.

In other words, your code wouldn't have worked any better in C# either. You need [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) when talking about an instance of `System.Type`:

```
If GetType(Rule.IRule).IsAssignableFrom(typeAsm) Then
```

Comment: What is the better choice(see my update): using IsAssignableFrom or myType.GetInterface("Rule.IRule") IsNot Nothing? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim: Personally I'm more of a fan of IsAssignableFrom just because it's already asking a Boolean question - and it's applicable in other situations. Don't sweat over it though :)

Comment: i've found out that it might be better (in my situation) to use: Not typeAsm.GetInterface(GetType(Rule.IRule).FullName) Is Nothing. Because the Interface IRule itself is assignable from IRule. That causes an Missing MethodException if i try to create an instance with: ruleObj = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(typeAsm, True), Rule.IRule).

Comment: @Tim: `GetInterface` is no better, because an abstract class can implement an interface.  You need to check `IsAbstract`.  It's also better to use the type cookie rather than the name whenever possible.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the IsAbstract tip :)

Answer (score 5):

In C#:

```
x is Class1
```

in VB.NET:

```
TypeOf x Is Class1
```

[Described here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx)

Comment: Figured I'd refresh before I posted and bang, here was the correct answer. +1

Comment: This answer is correct but will not do what he's trying to do.

Comment: Wow, I should have probably read the question better.  I guess I am guilty of that rushed response syndrome I find so annoying about this site...

Comment: Steve_ : I fixed the question to not be so misleading. Your answer, however, is incorrect for either question.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
If myType.GetInterface("Rule.IRule") IsNot Nothing Then
```

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this working answer. This is the best way (for me) because it besides avoids creating an instance of IRule itself. That is the problem with IsAssignableFrom. But i anyway choose Jon's answer because his answer is elaborated best.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong keyword.

The C# `is` keyword, and VB.Net's `TypeOf ... Is ...`, will check whether the instance is of a type that implements the interface.
Therefore, your code will check whether the `typeAsm` variable, which is a `System.Type` instance, implements the `IRule` interface.
Since the `System.Type` class doesn't implement `IRule`, it will always return `False`.

You are actually trying to check whether the *type represented by the `System.Type` instance* implements `IRule`.
To do that, you need to use the methods in the `System.Type` class.

For example:

```
 If typeAsm.GetInterface(GetType(Rule.IRule)) IsNot Nothing Then
```

Comment: `typeAsm.GetInterface(GetType(Rule.IRule).FullName) IsNot Nothing` is the correct way because GetInterface needs the Name as String. But thanks anyway.

Comment: `GetInterface` doesn't accept a `System.Type`, so your code snippet doesn't work.  Using the type name as a string is somewhat fragile and inefficient.  I really do think that calling `IsAssignableFrom` is the optimal way.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

Comment: @rerun: What part of **I need to know if an object implements an interface.** was unclear?

Comment: @Ben: The fact that the code in the question clearly doesn't match up with the text?

Comment: `TryCast` isn't what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Jon: Sure looks to me like `IRule` is an interface.

Comment: @Ben then you can use Type/GetInterface()

Comment: Thank you for the answer and clarifying that IsAssignableFrom combinated with IsAbstract might be the best way(see Update2).

Comment: @Tim: I think you missed the point of my `IsAbstract` suggestion.  You want to exclude not only `IRule` itself, but any interfaces derived from `IRule`, and any abstract classes implementing `IRule`, because using `Activator.CreateInstance` will fail for these as well.  Note that `CreateInstance` can fail for other reasons as well (you can't use it on a generic type pattern -- test with `ContainsGenericParameters`, or if there's no default constructor).

Comment: @Ben: No, i think i well understood your point. I want to create instances of IRule only for classes and not for instances or abstract classes. Therefor `IsAbstract` works perfectly. The other fail reasons are negligible because they could never happen in my situation.

Comment: @Tim: ya, you got it.  BTW if you're concerned about efficiency, swap the AndAlso to put the `IsAbstract` test in front, then the `IsAssignableFrom` check won't even be attempted for interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: @Ben: There is only one interface(IRule) in Rule.dll, hence the check for IsAssignableFrom is deciding in almost all cases and the swap wouldn't change anything.